# Store special characters (german)  SqlServer via php

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, pdo

I have a fedora machine acting as server, with apache running php 5.3

A scripts acts as an entry page for various sources sending me "messages".

The php script is called like: `serverAddress/phpScript.php?message=MyMessage` the message is then saved via PDO to connect to SqlServer 2008 db.

If the message contains any special characters (e.g. german), like: üäöß then in the db I will get some gibberish instead of the correct string: Ã¼Ã¤Ã¶ÃŸ

The db is perfectly capable of UTF-8 - I can connect and send/retrieve german characters without any issue with other tools (not via php).

Inside the php script:

- if I echo the input string I get the correct string üäöß
- if I save it to a file (log the input) I see the gibberish: Ã¼Ã¤Ã¶ÃŸ

**What is causing this behavior? How can I fix it?**

- multibyte is enabled (yum install php-mbstring followed by a apache restart)
- at the start of my php script I have:

```
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_http_output('UTF-8');
    mb_http_input('UTF-8');
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

- from what I understand the default encoding type when dealing with mssql via PDO is UTF-8

**New development:**

A colleague pointed me to the [PDO_DBLIB page](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/it/ref.pdo-dblib.php&ei=STVTUIS9DdHAtAbf8YD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNF4haeRz8gPq-1MKfB4OppngnqhNg&sig2=RaWBzaRJFg0J2UrNpUBZHQ&cad=rja) (visible only from cache in this moment) where I saw `$res->bindValue(':value', iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO8859-1', $value);`

I replaced all my  `$res->bindParam(':text',$text);` with  `$res->bindParam(':text',iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO8859-1',$text));` and everything worked :).

The mb_internal_encoding.... and all other lines were no longer needed.

**Why does it work when using the ISO8859-1 encoding?**

Answer (score 2):

A database may handle *special characters* without even supporting the Unicode set (which UTF-8 happens to be an encoding, specifically a variable-length one).

A character set is a mapping between numbers and characters. Unicode and ASCII are common examples of charsets. Unicode states  that the sign `€` maps to the number `8364` (really it uses the *code point* U+20AC). UTF-8 is a way to **encode** Unicode code points, and represents `U+20AC` with three bytes: `0xE2` `0x82` `0xAC`; UTF-16 is another encodind for Unicode code points, which always use two bytes: `0x20AC` ([link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm)). Both of these encodings refer to the same 8364th entry in the Unicode catalogue.

ASCII is both a charset and an encoding scheme: the ASCII character set maps number from 0 to 127 to 128 *human chars*, and the ASCII encoding requires a single byte.

Always remember that a String is a human concept. It's represented in a computer by the tuple `(byte_content, encoding)`. Let's say you want to store Unicode strings in your database. **Please, note: it's not necessary** to use the Unicode set if you just need to support German users. It's useful when you want to store Arabian, Chinese, Hebrew and German at the same time in the same column. MS SQLServer uses UCS-2 to encode Unicode, and this holds true for columns declared `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` (note the `N` prefix). So your first action will be checking if the target columns types are actually `nvarchar` (or `nchar`).

Then, let's assume that all input strings are UTF-8 encoded in your PHP script. You want to execute something like

```
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $utf8_encoded_text);
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), UTF-8 is the default string encoding. I hope it's smart enough to work with `NVARCHAR`, otherwise you may need to use [the extra options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628166%28v=sql.105%29).

Your colleague's solution **doesn't store** Unicode strings: it converts in the ISO-8859-1 space, then saves the bytes in *simple* `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` columns. The difference is that you won't be able to store character outside of the ISO-8859-1 space (eg Polish)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) on "Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App". By far one of the best articles I've seen on the subject. If you follow the guide and the issues are still present, then you know for sure that it's not your fault.